# Construct Two Linearly Independent Power Series Solutions to $(1+z^2)u''+3zu'+u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, power-series

> I am trying to construct two linearly independent, power series solutions to the ODE $$(1+z^2)u''+3zu'+u=0$$

My attempt:

Let $$u=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_kz^k\implies u'=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kA_kz^{k-1}\implies u''=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)A_kz^{k-2}$$

Substituting this into the ODE, I find that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left((k+2)(k+1)A_{k+2}+(k+1)^2A_k\right)z^k=0$$
Hence $u$ is a solution iff $$A_{k+2}=-\frac{k+1}{k+2}A_k \ \ \ k\geq 0$$
I do not see how to proceed, especially considering there are no intial conditions to find $A_0$ and $A_1$. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Take $A_0=0$ and $A_1=1$ and compute one solution. Then take $A_0=1$ and $A_1=0$ and compute another. You will get two linearly independent solutions.

Comment: One of the solutions provided is $$u_1(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k}.$$ How does one obtain this? I can the individual terms of this series, but do I put it in a form like this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a mistake in your reccurent relation
$$A_{k+2}=-\frac{1}{k+2}A_k \ \ \ k\geq 0$$
I get from your last equality

$$A_{2n}=(\frac {-1}2)^n\frac {A_0}{n!}$$
$$\implies u_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac {-z^2}2)^n\frac {A_0}{n!}$$
Which is not exact...Check again your last equality

---

***Edit***
from this 
$$A_{k+2}=-\frac{k+1}{k+2}A_k \ \ \ k\geq 0$$
you evaluate $A_2,A_4,A_6$
$$A_2=-\frac 12A_0$$
$$A_4=-\frac 34A_1=\frac {1\times 3}{2 \times 4}A_0$$
$$A_6=-\frac {1\times 3 \times 5}{2 \times 4 \times 6}A_0$$
Can you deduce the pattern ?

In the denominator you have that
$$2\times 4 \times 6.... =2 \times 2 \times 2 \times ...... \times 1 \times 2  \times 3..=2^nn!$$

So that
$$A_{2n}=(-1)^n \frac {1 \times 3 \times 5 ...}{2^n(n!)}A_0$$
Do the same for the numerator you have 
$$1\times 3 \times 5 \times ...$$
Wehave that
$$1\times 3 \times 5 \times ..= \frac  {1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6} {2\times 4 \times 6}=\frac   {(2n)!}{2^n (n!)}$$
Finally 
$$\boxed {A_{2n}=(-1)^n \frac {(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}A_0}$$
$$u_1=\sum_ {n=0}^\infty(-1)^n \frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2}(\frac {z}{2})^{2n}$$

---

Note that you can check the solution by direct integration

$$(1+z^2)u''+3zu'+u=0$$
$$(1+z^2)u''+2zu'+zu'+u=0$$
$$((1+z^2)u')'+(zu)'=0$$
integrate
$$(1+z^2)u'+zu=K_1$$

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, I think I have fixed it. I am still unsure of how to find a solution though.

Comment: yw @Bell and yes you have to put the solution in the form of the provided answer with two series ...One for $z^{2n}$ and another one for $z^{2n+1}$ and it dosent matter that you have the constant $A_0,A_1$

Comment: I have the individual terms, but how do I put them in the form of a single power series?

Comment: @Bell with your formula evaluate $A_2$ it means $k=0$ then evaluate $A_4$  then you infere a fiormula a general formula for $A_ {2n}$ in function of $A_0$

Comment: Do the same for $A_3$ and $A_5$ evaluate in function of $A_1$ then infere a general formula for $A_{2n+1}$ Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: I still can't seem to get the general formula. Are you able to put a derivation in your comment?

Comment: Ok I will add some lines in my answer

Comment: @Bell I added more lines hope it helps